# html Select not working in mobile browsers but working well on desktop chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, select

Its feeling as if the select options are not getting clicked at all or are responding very slowly.All the other things in my app are working normal.
when I click on the select input boxes it works fine on my computer but not well on my cell phone.I tried using several other android phones but it did not help me.
I have used angular js routs to create new pages.
Here is my website link http://gananatraj.com/gdanceapp/www/#/home

Login as trainer@trainer.com
password as password

I first noticed this issue after updating google chrome mobile browser to the latest version .that is version 53.x.x.x. But now noticed issue on mobile mozilla browser as well.
Other website`s select options work fine.Do not know the exact cause for the issue.

its like a mobile app.. The select is not working on chrome and Mozilla mobile browsers.I cannot figure out what is wrong...Can anyone help me trouble-shoot this issue??
Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Having a similar issue on my end. Maybe they changed something in webkit.

Comment: How to solve the issue?

Comment: issue is still not solved ..anyone who knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm also running into an issue like this.

Comment: What scripts do you have loading in your page?